# Why does Chrome store __RequestVerificationCookie for localhost, but not other cookies?

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cookies

Everyone claims a domain must have two dots in order for a cookie to be stored, but that cannot be true, because Chrome is storing the cooking named "__RequestVerificationToken" received through the Set-Cookie header from ASP.NET; however, it refuses to store other cookies.  I literally am sending a virtually identical cookie with a virtually identical Set-Cookie header, and yet Chrome is refusing to store it.  The path is "/", just like the other one.  No domain is set.  The only difference is the name.  Is Chrome giving "__RequestVerificationToken" some kind of special treatment?

Comment: Seems that it may be storing it as a result of setting HttpCookie.Expires to DateTime.MinValue.  That causes the cookie writing to NOT include the "expires" string, which causes the cookie to become a session cookie and is stored for localhost.  No idea why those cookies are stored, but the others are not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Chrome will save "session" cookies for "localhost", but not "permanent" cookies. No idea why it makes the exception for "session" cookies, but the "permanent" ones aren't stored because cookies are only supposed to be stored for 2nd level domains (domains with at least 2 dots, which localhost is not).

"permanent" cookies are cookies that DO set an expiration date, which is a bit  counter-intuitive, but they're "permanent" in the sense that they survive across browser restarts unlike "session" cookies which are supposed to be deleted when the browser closes.  In reality, they're all relatively permanent, because Chrome/Firefox typically don't delete the session cookies when the browser closes, thanks to features like "continue where I left off" and "restore my tabs when the browser restarts".

Another takeaway is that we may as well not set an expiration on any kind of session or auth cookie at all, because it offers the following advantages: 1. it works on localhost, 2. it more secure in that they stand a chance of being deleted when the browser closes, and 3. they persist across browser sessions anyway if the user has the browser configured to do so, so setting a long timeout isn't necessary.  Setting an expiration on the cookie also doesn't do you any good anyway, because it's just another value to sync with the server-side session, the value isn't sent to the server with the cookie anyway, so it's useless, and utimately the server-side expiration for the token (stored in session or database) is authoritative anyway.  So just don't set an expiration on your session or auth-related cookies.